# PHP Inheritance: If A then Must Set B

Tags: php, class, inheritance

So, I tried to Google this but don't know what this kind of situation is called...

I'm working on my first use of class inheritance, where a parent class defines a set of methods and then several other classes extend that parent.

What I was wondering, is it possible to do something like this:

```
class foo {
  private bar = false;
  private baz = NULL;
}
```

Now let's say I have:

```
class foobar extends foo { }
```

I'd like to be able to have a condition in "foo" that says if any class extends "foo" and sets "bar = true" then "baz" must be set (ie. not null), or else throw an exception.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Waitasecond... If the variables are declared `private`, the inherited classes won't have access to them anyways. So what's the point of this?

Comment: Well they do have access if you define a getter and setter in the parent, or you could change them to protected. The point of this is to foolproof some stuff. Basically I have a parent that has a lot of helpful 'behind the scenes' stuff baked in, and I want people who are using the code to extend this rather than use it or edit it directly, and I'm trying to create a scenario where if they want to enable a certain feature (bar = true) then they get a very specific error message if they don't include the required information (baz != null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems possible by using a [magic setter function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) that you define in `foo`, but comes with a serious caveat. Magic getters and setters *fire only when you access an inaccessible property.*

When operating inside a class, all properties, no matter whether declared private, public or protected, are usually accessible, so the magic getter and setter functions will not fire. There is only one exception: Properties that were declared `private` in an ancestor class. Those will be hidden (inaccessible) to descendant classes, and the magic functions will fire.

This means that you will need to declare `bar` and `baz` in `foo`. It wouldn't work if you would declare them in `foobar`, because they would become accessible.

With this in mind, the following will work as you want:

```
class foo {
  private $bar = false;
  private $baz = NULL;

  public function __set($name, $value)
   {
     if ($name == "bar") 
      { if ($value == true)
         {
           if ($this->baz == null) 
            throw new Exception();
         }
      }
   } 
}

class foobar extends foo {

     function test()
      {
       $this->bar = "TEST";   
      }

 }


 $foobar = new foobar();
 $foobar->test();  // Will throw an exception
```

If you want to read `bar` and `baz` from within `foobar`, you will also need to define a magic getter function.

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome. I'm somewhat surprised myself that this is possible :) Having to declare properties private in an ancestor to have getters and setters fire seems somewhat arbitrary, but I tested it and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a construct function in the second class.

```
class foo {
  private bar = false;
  private baz = NULL;
  public function __construct() {
    if ($this->bar && is_null($this->baz)) // throw exception
  }
}
class foobar extends foo {
  public function __construct($baz) {
    $this->baz = $baz;
    $this->bar = true;
    parent::__construct(); // Now run the parent's constructor
  }
}
```

Many different ways to do it...

Comment: Yes, but the real reason I want to do this is I think that *I* may not be the person who writes the "foobar" class. So, if someone tries to use a certain functionality from the parent (bar = true) then they must also provide some information (baz != null).     Since my concern is to catch an incomplete extension of the parent class I wouldn't want the implementation to be dependent on any code inside the child class.